# Error while deploying an application on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have installed Google Cloud platform on Ubuntu following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#running_hello_world). However I stumbled and got an error while deploying, I lost track of the error. But check the screenshot for more information,
http://imageshack.com/a/img908/4922/PuNPtN.png

*chat-server-973 is the id of my project.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used a python app engine app engine instance but from what I remember it looks like you might be using app.yml where you should be using app.yaml